# Will $\lfloor{xe}\rfloor = \left\lfloor\left\lfloor\frac{xe}{e-1}\right\rfloor(e-1)\right\rfloor$ $\forall$ $x\geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory

If we take a number $\lfloor{xe}\rfloor$ and another number $\left\lfloor\lfloor{\frac{xe}{e-1}\rfloor}(e-1)\right\rfloor$, then can we say that they are equal $\forall x\geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$?
If not, when? 
I think they are pretty equal since $a \lfloor\frac{b}{a}\rfloor + r=b$ where $0\leq r < a$ and here, $a=e-1 < 1.7$. 
I am not sure if they hold infinitely or not, that's my question.

Comment: What does "equal infinitely" mean?

Comment: Is it true for $x=e-1$.

Comment: Check - what happens when $x=1$?

Comment: @JaideepKhare it doesn't hold. But check for some more values.

Comment: @KennyLau I think OP wants to ask whether is it true $\forall x \in \Mathbb R$.

Comment: I have edited the Question

Comment: Please avoid `\bigg`.

Comment: I'm afraid that my suspicion turned out to be [valid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2314374/11619) - the OP is trying to cheat in a CODECHEF challenge. All: this month ALL questions having an integer multiple of $e$ inside floor function are VERBOTEN, STRENG UNTERSAGT, FÖRBJUDNA, FORBIDDEN... Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

There are many values of $x$ for which this is not true; for instance, $x=101$

- [LHS = 274](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(101*e))
- [RHS = 273](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(floor(101*e%2F(e-1))*(e-1)))

Comment: I strongly doubt this inaccuracy goes away as $x$ gets large: for instance, around $x=110100$ they were different in 5 of the 7 cases I checked.

Comment: As far as finding the cases where there is no inaccuracy, my best answer is good luck. The discrepancy stays bounded above by 3 for all $x$, and so as $x$ gets big you're looking to know the exact value of $1/(e-1)$ to very high accuracy. That doesn't seem so impossible, but it might not be easy to make any uniform statement.